# Docker amazon linux2022: openjdk-17 renturned a non zero code: 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

My dockerfile looks like this. But when i build, i get the following error. If i do this on my docker image and do wget with the bash on it, it strangely works.

```
docker build -t mydocker:latest


FROM amazonlinux:2022
RUN mkdir -p /APP
WORKDIR APP
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1/
RUN wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk17/0d483333a00540d886896bac774ff48b/35/GPL/openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
RUN yum install tar -y
RUN yum install gzip -y
COPY openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /APP
RUN tar xvf openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz


Step 11/11 : RUN tar xvf openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
 ---> Running in 83a94400e4b7
jdk-17/bin/jar
jdk-17/bin/jarsigner
jdk-17/bin/java
jdk-17/bin/javac
jdk-17/bin/javadoc
jdk-17/bin/javap
jdk-17/bin/jcmd
jdk-17/bin/jconsole
jdk-17/bin/jdb
jdk-17/bin/jdeprscan
jdk-17/bin/jdeps
jdk-17/bin/jfr
jdk-17/bin/jhsdb
jdk-17/bin/jimage
jdk-17/bin/jinfo
jdk-17/bin/jlink
jdk-17/bin/jmap
jdk-17/bin/jmod
jdk-17/bin/jpackage
jdk-17/bin/jps
jdk-17/bin/jrunscript
jdk-17/bin/jshell
jdk-17/bin/jstack
jdk-17/bin/jstat
jdk-17/bin/jstatd
jdk-17/bin/keytool
jdk-17/bin/rmiregistry
jdk-17/bin/serialver
jdk-17/conf/logging.properties
jdk-17/conf/management/jmxremote.access
jdk-17/conf/management/jmxremote.password.template
jdk-17/conf/management/management.properties
jdk-17/conf/net.properties
jdk-17/conf/sdp/sdp.conf.template
jdk-17/conf/security/java.policy
jdk-17/conf/security/java.security
jdk-17/conf/security/policy/README.txt
jdk-17/conf/security/policy/limited/default_US_export.policy
jdk-17/conf/security/policy/limited/default_local.policy
jdk-17/conf/security/policy/limited/exempt_local.policy
jdk-17/conf/security/policy/unlimited/default_US_export.policy
jdk-17/conf/security/policy/unlimited/default_local.policy
jdk-17/conf/sound.properties
jdk-17/include/classfile_constants.h
jdk-17/include/jawt.h
jdk-17/include/jdwpTransport.h
jdk-17/include/jni.h
jdk-17/include/jvmti.h
jdk-17/include/jvmticmlr.h
jdk-17/include/linux/jawt_md.h
jdk-17/include/linux/jni_md.h
jdk-17/jmods/java.base.jmod

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your `Dockerfile` to be:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2022
RUN mkdir -p /APP
WORKDIR APP
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1/
RUN wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk17/0d483333a00540d886896bac774ff48b/35/GPL/openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
RUN yum install tar -y
RUN yum install gzip -y
RUN tar xvf openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -C /APP
```

and was able to create the container just fine.  If I used your `Dockerfile` I got:

```
Step 10/11 : COPY openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /APP
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz: file does not exist
```

because `COPY` copies from the host file system, not the Docker file system.  Perhaps your local copy of `openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` is truncated.

Alternately, since you're using the Amazon Linux docker image you could use Amazon's Java (Corretto) with something like:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2022
RUN mkdir -p /APP
WORKDIR APP
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1/
RUN yum install tar -y
RUN yum install gzip -y
RUN yum install java-11-amazon-corretto-headless -y
```

Assuming you want the "headless" version.

My docker version is "20.10.18".

Comment: i love you! You are the best!

Comment: What does -C mean here?

Comment: From [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Option-Summary.html#g_t_002d_002ddirectory) "When this option is specified, tar will change its current directory to dir before performing any operations.".  This allows you to extract from one place and place it in another. Now that I try it you don't need the `-C` as the file is already in `/APP` because of the `WORKDIR`.  It doesn't hurt but it's unneeded.